# ¿ Como añadir dos imágenes en un DIV de un tema de WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-imagenes

La pregunta es un poco escasa, pues no se por donde empezar.
Estoy editando un tema de WordPress (Howello), mas concretamente lo que debo editar es un plugin, WP Hotel Booking.
Es un tema para hotel-rural y entrando en cada una de las habitaciones se explican detalles de la misma, añadir comentarios, etc.
Captura de la pagina : https://ibb.co/kYer2f
https://ibb.co/hf1zoL
Al final de la pagina hay imágenes que enlazan con el resto de las correspondientes habitaciones.
https://ibb.co/gM25TL
Bien, el hotel tiene la posibilidad de reservar 4 habitaciones o el hotel completo.
He configurado casi por completo, pero en cada una delas habitaciones, solo se muestran dos imágenes de enlace a las otras habitaciones.
Necesitaría que se mostraran 4 imágenes, que son el resto de habitaciones.
El autor del plugin me dice que esto lo puedo hacer desde el archivo que muestro a continuación.
Mi experiencia en PHP es nula, y por mas que veo el archivo, no como editar.
Viendo este archivo, ¿ podrían decirme a que otros archivos me lleva este ?
Esta claro que desde este no puedo añadir las imágenes.
Les muestro una captura de los los archivos que tiene el tema, el plugin.
https://ibb.co/d4t12f
Imagino que que la información que muestro sea escasa, ya me dirán si debo editarla y añadir mas archivos.
solo espero puedan darme alguna idea de si este archivo me lleva a otro el cual tenga el código de las imágenes, 
Gracias.
Esta es la dirección de la casa, si quieren verla: lamimosas.org

```js
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying content single room.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/wp-hotel-booking/content-single-room.php.
 *
 * @author  ThimPress, leehld
 * @package WP-Hotel-Booking/Templates
 * @version 1.6
 */

/**
 * Prevent loading this file directly
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit(); ?>

<?php
/**
 * hotel_booking_before_single_product hook
 */
do_action( 'hotel_booking_before_single_product' );

if ( post_password_required() ) {
 echo get_the_password_form();

 return;
} ?>

<div id="room-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'hb_single_room' ); ?>>

 <?php
 /**
  * hotel_booking_before_loop_room_summary hook
  */
 do_action( 'hotel_booking_before_single_room' );
 ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">

  <?php
  /**
   * hotel_booking_single_room_title hook
   */
  do_action( 'hotel_booking_single_room_title' );

  /**
   * hotel_booking_loop_room_price hook
   */
  do_action( 'hotel_booking_loop_room_price' );

  /**
   * hotel_booking_single_room_gallery hook
   */
  do_action( 'hotel_booking_single_room_gallery' );

  /**
   * hotel_booking_single_room_infomation hook
   */
  do_action( 'hotel_booking_single_room_infomation' );
  ?>

    </div>

 <?php
 /**
  * hotel_booking_after_single_room hook
  */
 do_action( 'hotel_booking_after_single_room' );
 ?>

</div>

<?php
/**
 * hotel_booking_after_single_product hook
 */
do_action( 'hotel_booking_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido mi propósito, y quiero intentar explicar como.
Este plugin tiene la opción de editar las habitaciones y el tipo de habitaciones.
Pues bien, tiene tres tipos por defecto: *Standard, Bronze, Luxury.*
Como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionado el tipo *standar*, al pie d cada habitación se muestran el resto de las que tiene la casa.

Otra opción es en: habitaciones >>> edición rápida (sobre cada habitación) >> tipo de habitación . Se lo muestro en imágenes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo espero a verlo explicado bien para que pueda ayudar a otro usuario.
Siempre estaré dispuesto a ayudar con este plugin al que lo necesite.
Ahora la parte baja de cada habitación, se ve de la siguiente manera, mostrando el resto de habitaciones, con un slider automático que va mostrándolas todas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

he estado mirando tus capturas, la web y el código que has pasado. El código es el que se ejecuta en cada una de las habitaciones que se muestra, es decir, es la "plantilla" para cada elemento del grid de habitaciones. Tu lo que necesitas es tocar el código donde se llama a ese fichero. ya que ahí seguramente sea donde se este poniendo el limite de las 2 habitaciones. Digamos que esas dos habitaciones te las muestra como productos relacionados. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias @MiguelAngelGonzalez por buena intención. Eso es lo que yo necesitaba saber, cual es el archivo que debo modificar, gracias.

Comment: Tienes que hacer un poco de investigación y con algun programa que te permita buscar dentro de los ficheros, buscar el que llama a este. Por ejemplo, en Sublime text 3 te permite buscar dentro de los archivos del proyecto. Solo tienes que buscar el nombre de tu fichero y te aparecerá uno o mas ficheros que llaman a este. Uno de esos sera el que debas modificar.